# Timeout Issue in testing Protractor with Jasmine

Tags: protractor

I am using Protractor to test my Angular Application.
I am using the modules i created as a pre-condition to test my cases.
When i run my test before the pre-condition met the browser is exiting.
Please check my pre-condition call in my test and suggest any solution to solve this issue.

```
beforeAll(function (done) {
    async.series([
            function (callback1) {
                jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1900000;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log("inside timeout.....");
                    callback1();
                }, 500);
                browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
            },
            function (callback2) {
                registerNewUser(myCredentials, function (res) {
                    //browser.waitForAngular();
                    myCredentials = res;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
                    console.log(res);
                    expect(res).not.toBeNull();
                    //browser.waitForAngular();
                    // browser.sleep(5000)
                    callback2(res);
                    //browser.pause(10000);
                    // browser.sleep(5000)
                    browser.waitForAngular();



                });
            }
        ],

        function (err) {
            // browser.sleep(5000)
            console.log("Inside done");
            browser.waitForAngular();
            done();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `browser.driver.sleep(500)` to befire or after your operations. :)